# Linking brew installed openblas to /usr/local

Tags: r, openblas

I have installed `R` that in turns installs `openblas` - but *not* to `/usr/local` :

```
==> openblas
openblas is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides BLAS and LAPACK in the Accelerate framework.

For compilers to find openblas you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"

For pkg-config to find openblas you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
```

My primary use case for `openblas` is with `R` and `scipy`. The latter _no longer supports the Macos Accelerate package`: so there's no problem with redirecting to brew. The former will be using the brew anyways: so I see no harm in doing this. But *how* to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps made this work:

- Uninstall `openblas` via brew:

  `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openblas`
- Reinstall `R`

  `brew install R`
- Manually create symbolic link to `/usr/local` :

  `sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/openblas /usr/local`

Now we have `R` !

```
$R

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0 (64-bit)

 .. 

>
```